# C++: How to retrieve the list of Firefox plugins installed?

Tags: c++, firefox, visual-c++

How to retrieve the list of Firefox plugins installed in C++?  I have the code to get it through Javascript, but i don't know how to use that in C++.
Please help.

```
if(navigator.plugins)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < navigator.plugins.length; i++)
    {
        alert(navigator.plugins[i].name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code won't tell you the list of Firefox plugins unless it's being run by Firefox. So asking for a C++ equivalent doesn't really make sense since a C++ program can never be in a context where this makes sense. (It can't have its source code loaded and executed by Firefox.)

Comment: They are loaded based on registry keys & known paths; http://mike.kaply.com/2012/02/16/how-firefox-loads-plugins/

Answer (score 0):

- For Plugins DLL look here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference/Plug-in_Basics#Plug-ins%20and%20Platform%20Independence

and search for "**How Gecko finds plug-ins**"

- For addons:

Your only choice is to enumerate firefox directories.

extensions available for all users :

> C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\extensions

extensions available per user basis:

> %USERPROFILE%\Application
>   Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\%PROFILENAME%\extensions   (XP)
>
> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\%PROFILENAME%\extensions
>   (Vista, win7)

Note that %PROFILENAME% is not environmental variable, but randomly created name during profile creation.

You should enum Profiles folder to get this, basicaly most users has just one profile.

When you get into profile directory, take a look at **addons.sqlite**.

There are infos about addon (enable/disable state, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

You need to scan the profiles folders of firefox.
Usually:
C:\Users\login_name\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\xxxx.default

In there if you want extensions, just open the sqlite database named **extensions.sqlite** and read the values of the table **addon**.

If you want the plugins you can try to parse the file **pluginreg.dat**